# Failing to set / retrieve data using NSKeyedArchiver / NSKeyedUnarchiver on file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I am trying to save some persistent data on an iOS app using NSKeyedArchiver to write to a file, and I would like to retrieve this data later using NSKeyedUnarchiver. I created a very basic application to test some code, but with no success.
Here are the methods that I am using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Note *myNote = [self loadNote];

    myNote.author = @"MY NAME";

    [self saveNote:myNote]; // Trying to save this note containing author's name

    myNote = [self loadNote]; // Trying to retrieve the note saved to the file

    NSLog(@"%@", myNote.author); // Always logs (null) after loading data
}

-(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"myFile"];
    return filePath;
}

-(void)saveNote:(Note*)note
{
    bool success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:note toFile:[self filePath]];
    NSLog(@"%i", success); // This line logs 1 (success)
}

-(Note *)loadNote
{
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self filePath]];
}
```

The class that I am using to test this code is as follows:

Note.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Note : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property NSString *title;
@property NSString *author;
@property bool published;

@end
```

Note.m

```
#import "Note.h"

@implementation Note

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.title = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
        self.author = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"author"];
        self.published = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:@"published"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.title forKey:@"title"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.author forKey:@"author"];
    [aCoder encodeBool:self.published forKey:@"published"];
}

@end
```

I have seen similar examples using NSUserDefaults (https://blog.soff.es/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding), but I would like to save this data to a file, because as far as I know NSUserDefaults is used mainly to store user preferences, and not general data. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what happens the first time your app runs and you call your `loadNote:` method and there isn't anything saved yet.

The line:

```
Note *myNote = [self loadNote];
```

will result in `myNote` being `nil` since nothing was loaded. Now think how that cascades through the rest of your code.

You need to handle this initial case of there being no saved data.

```
Note *myNote = [self loadNote];
if (!myNote) {
    myNote = [[Note alloc] init];
    // Setup the initial note as needed
    myNote.title = ...
}
```